# search a string and print the string and it's header

Tags: linux, shell-script

I need to search for a string (number here), and print it's header or title using grep or awk or anything.

please check this example:

Input file content:

```
#####
Production_Broad:
#####
678
544
#####
IGHTY_BBBT:
#####
1666
2515
2516
2517
2518
#####
Jaguar:
#####
280
#####
Loyalty:
#####
5179
#####
MC_Addr:
#####
544
577890
#####
erce_Ban_1:
#####
7455
5656
```

I want to search for the number "2515", and it gives me below output:

```
IGHTY_BBBT:
2515
```

and if i searched for "5179", the output should be as below:

```
Loyalty:
5179
```

Comment: This is really not that hard. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried this command after putting source file "out" and required numbers in file list "for i in `cat list`;do if [[ `grep -w $i out` ]];then grep -w $i out;else echo $i"  :not found";fi ;done", but i got no headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If headers are identified by those `#####` lines, and the list of IDs to search for is in a `ids.txt` file (one per line), you could do:

```
awk '
  !ids_processed{ids[$0]; next}
  $0 == "#####" {getline header; getline; next}
  $0 in ids     {print header ORS $0}' ids.txt ids_processed=1 input.txt
```

For instance, if `ids.txt` contains

```
2515
544
577890
```

On your sample, that would give:

```
Production_Broad:
544
IGHTY_BBBT:
2515
MC_Addr:
544
MC_Addr:
577890
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
awk '{if(match($0,":")) header=$0; if($0 == 2516) printf("%s\n%s\n",header,$0)}' input_file.txt
```

Where "2516" is the number you are searching for.

obs: I'm assuming that all the labels ends with ":".

Comment: Can i put the numbers i am searching for in a file (not only 2516)??

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** approach:

```
awk -v RS="#####" -v num=2515 '$0~/[0-9a-zA-Z_]+:/{ 
     getline nl; if (nl~num){sub("\n", "", $0); printf("%s%d\n",$0,num)}}' file
```

The output:

```
IGHTY_BBBT:
2515
```

---

`RS="#####"` - treating `#####` as record separator

`-v num=2515` - a variable containing search number

`$0~/[0-9a-zA-Z_]+:/` - capturing *header* line

`getline nl` - get next record containing numbers

`if (nl~num)` - if search number is matched within a line of numbers

Comment: Can i put the numbers i am searching for in a file (not only 2515) ??

Comment: @Fady.Fouad, do you want to search by multiple numbers?

Comment: Yes by multiple numbers in a file

Comment: @Fady.Fouad, and how they will be separated, by space or by newline within a file?

Comment: By new line within file.